# Chrome App Full Screen Issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome app that uses the webview, so right now I have it open  my url in the the window without the url bar and buttons ect. So it loads the page in full screen. What I'm wondering is it possible to disable certain key presses from exiting the full screen. For example if you press esc or alt tab or the windows/mac key it allows you to access other things going on in the background anyway to disable this? I need to try to make it secure so only by possible entering a password you can get out of the webview. This is going to be for people to take quizzes on so I don't want them to be able to access outside resources when doing there quiz. Any help would be great or if I need to go in a different direction.

Answer (score 1):

For now, consider using a [chromebook in kiosk mode](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3134673?hl=en) with a [kiosk app](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled).

In non kiosk mode, full access to keyboard (locking a user into an app) is not possible today. There has been some discussion (internal to the team at least) regarding how to support this for the use cases of e.g. remote desktop viewers (want to send all keystrokes to the remote computer).

Comment: Keep an eye out for the Asus Chromebox (http://promos.asus.com/us/chrome-os/chromebox/). This is probably going to be the cheapest way to deploy a kiosk-mode app if you already have a monitor.

Comment: Would this work the same with chrome on windows? That's what I'm using not a chromebook.